# How to get exact start date and end date of every quarter of a given year in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get the exact start and end dates (month, day and year) of a given year.

E.g., 2008
Jan. 1, 2008
Mar, 30, 2008

Any thoughts on how to do this?

```
array = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]

array.each do |a|

   #code to get array of date for a (year)   
end
```

Comment: I might be feeling a little dense here, but I don't think the start and end dates of the quarters change that much between years. Or are you referring to the first and last business day in the quarter, which is a completely different kettle of fish altogether?

Comment: yes. you're right but I just wanted to get an array of the dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following thing is more ruby way

```
array = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
quarters = []
array.each do |a|
  @date = Date.parse("1.1.#{a}")  unless @date
  4.times do
    quarters << [@date.beginning_of_quarter, @date.end_of_quarter]
    @date = @date.end_of_quarter+1.day
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, I've forgot about AS helpers `beginning_of_quarter` and `end_of_quarter` =). `@date ||= Date.parse("1.1.#{a}") will be better

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
quarters = []
array.each do |a|
  date = Date.parse("1.1.#{a}")
  4.times do
    quarters << [date, date+3.month-1.day]
    date += 3.month
  end
end
quarters

#=> [[Mon, 01 Jan 2007, Sat, 31 Mar 2007], [Sun, 01 Apr 2007, Sat, 30 Jun 2007], [Sun, 01 Jul 2007, Sun, 30 Sep 2007], [Mon, 01 Oct 2007, Mon, 31 Dec 2007], [Tue, 01 Jan 2008, Mon, 31 Mar 2008], [Tue, 01 Apr 2008, Mon, 30 Jun 2008], [Tue, 01 Jul 2008, Tue, 30 Sep 2008], [Wed, 01 Oct 2008, Wed, 31 Dec 2008], [Thu, 01 Jan 2009, Tue, 31 Mar 2009], [Wed, 01 Apr 2009, Tue, 30 Jun 2009], [Wed, 01 Jul 2009, Wed, 30 Sep 2009], [Thu, 01 Oct 2009, Thu, 31 Dec 2009], [Fri, 01 Jan 2010, Wed, 31 Mar 2010], [Thu, 01 Apr 2010, Wed, 30 Jun 2010], [Thu, 01 Jul 2010, Thu, 30 Sep 2010], [Fri, 01 Oct 2010, Fri, 31 Dec 2010]]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to get crazy and do it all in one line

```
[2007, 2008, 2009, 2010].inject([]){|quarters, year| quarters += [1, 4, 7, 10].collect{|month| [Time.parse("#{month}/01/#{year}").beginning_of_quarter, Time.parse("#{month}/01/#{year}").end_of_quarter]}.flatten}
```

not super expressive, but a cool exercise! I <3 inject

returns:

```
[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 -0500 2007, Sat Mar 31 23:59:59 -0400 2007, Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 -0400 2007, Sat Jun 30 23:59:59 -0400 2007, Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 -0400 2007, Sun Sep 30 23:59:59 -0400 2007, Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 -0400 2007, Mon Dec 31 23:59:59 -0500 2007, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 -0500 2008, Mon Mar 31 23:59:59 -0400 2008, Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 -0400 2008, Mon Jun 30 23:59:59 -0400 2008, Tue Jul 01 00:00:00 -0400 2008, Tue Sep 30 23:59:59 -0400 2008, Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 -0400 2008, Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 -0500 2008, Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 -0500 2009, Tue Mar 31 23:59:59 -0400 2009, Wed Apr 01 00:00:00 -0400 2009, Tue Jun 30 23:59:59 -0400 2009, Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 -0400 2009, Wed Sep 30 23:59:59 -0400 2009, Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 -0400 2009, Thu Dec 31 23:59:59 -0500 2009, Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 -0500 2010, Wed Mar 31 23:59:59 -0400 2010, Thu Apr 01 00:00:00 -0400 2010, Wed Jun 30 23:59:59 -0400 2010, Thu Jul 01 00:00:00 -0400 2010, Thu Sep 30 23:59:59 -0400 2010, Fri Oct 01 00:00:00 -0400 2010, Fri Dec 31 23:59:59 -0500 2010]
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic one:

```
def get_dates(year, quarter)
    date = Date.new(year, quarter * 3)

    [date.beginning_of_quarter, date.end_of_quarter]
end
```